# 80 girls cartoon movie with singing and flower-name theme

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

Looking for a 80s cartoon movie for girls. The girls lived in a magical kingdom and had to restore something (Either love or friendship or something) there are songs that the girls sing throughout the movie and at the end.

The antagonist is an evil woman wearing purple. I though her name or a name of a character was “petunia’ or something like that. The antagonist was evil and ugly and the girl's end song turned her pretty. I though the The girl's names were flower-based too.

*(It's not Rose Petal Place)*

Comment: It ‘“peppermint rose”the movie ^_^

Comment: If you have a few minutes to spare, you can write a [self answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) (and accept it too, after a while), so that future users will better see there is an answer to the question.

Answer (score 4):

Per the original poster's comment above, the answer to this inquiry is a [1992 made-for-television movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8164038/) based on [Peppermint Rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peppermint_Rose).